# Why is the capacitor voltage Vin*D?

Tags: capacitor, pwm, filter, low-pass

I'm trying to understand turning a pwm signal to a analog signal. 
From what I saw online I found that using a lowpass filter, the capacitor voltage is Vin*DutyCycle. 
This was given as a fact and I was wondering where does this rule come from? From what equation?. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The voltage will ideally approach the average input voltage. If the input waveform is a square wave with duty cycle D such that D = ton/(ton + toff) and the voltage is 0V for toff and Vin for ton, then the average is Vin*D.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the low-pass filter is to get the average value of the PWM signal.

It should be easy to see, that that the average value is Vin*dutycycle.